# Mobilefirst Error 500

Tags: ibm-mobilefirst, mobilefirst-server

We have uploaded the .war file , wlapp and adapter. How can we resolve this issue?
The error is the url of .war file.

> Error 500: javax.servlet.ServletException: Worklight Console
>   initialization failed.Logged Exception:
>   com.worklight.server.database.api.WorklightDataSourceException:
>   FWLSE0194E: MobileFirst Server cannot be started because of failure
>   while getting a connection from data-source bound to resource
>   reference: jdbc/WorklightDS. Make sure the database is up, the
>   credentials are correct and the driver is available for the server

Comment: Did you set the JDBC driver? are you sure the username/password is correct? are you sure the database is available and that nothing in the network prevents connecting to it?

Comment: We haved used configuration tool and jdbc driver are installed . I tried to test connection they are all successful.

Comment: Add the server.xml file (upload it to dropbox)

Comment: server.xml on MF Server right?

Comment: of the application server you have deployed mfp to.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have stopped the middleware server and start it again where my .war project is located. The issue was resolve.